# How to run wasm on d8

Tags: v8, webassembly

I have a wasm file fib.wasm which contains function fib(n). 
If run it in the browser, we can do

```
var module, functions = {};
fetch('fib.wasm')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => new Uint8Array(buffer))
  .then(binary => {
    var moduleArgs = {
      wasmBinary: binary,
      onRuntimeInitialized: function () {
        functions.fib =
          module.cwrap('fib',
                       'number',
                       ['number']);
        onReady();
      }
    };
    module = Module(moduleArgs);
  });
```

If in Node, since fetch is not implemented, we can do

```
const fs = require('fs')
const buf = fs.readFileSync('fib.wasm')
(async () => { res = await WebAssembly.instantiate(buf); })()
const { fib } = res.instance.exports
```

However, in d8 shell, both ways involves functions undefined. How can we run wasm in d8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `d8` shell has a function `read()` which reads a file from disk. It takes an optional parameter to specify binary mode. So the following should work:

```
const buf = read('fib.wasm', 'binary');
let res;
WebAssembly.instantiate(buf).then((x) => res = x, (error) => console.log(error));
const { fib } = res.instance.exports;
```

Comment: Thank you so much but it showed "TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object".

Comment: If your module requires imports, then you must provide them, e.g.: `WebAssembly.instantiate(buf, {import1: foo, import2: bar}).then(...)`. This depends on the Wasm module you're loading.