# How to trigger V8 "tiering up" with Liftoff [Arm64]

Tags: javascript, security, arm, v8, lldb

Working with V8 right now and I am trying to trying to trigger the Tiering Up of the Liftoff Assembler found in `v8/v8/src/wasm/baseline/arm64/liftoff-assembler-arm64.h`

Does anyone know how to do this? Or if it's possible to construct a WASM Module complex enough for the Tiering up to occur -- I guess my basic goal is to exhaust the tiering budget.

Even a preexisting module that is *known* to be big/complex enough to trigger it would be much appreciated.

I'm currently debugging in `lldb` and am unfortunately unable to see any tiering up from  Liftoff.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

(V8 developer here.)

Module complexity is irrelevant for tiering. Even an empty function in a module that contains nothing else will get optimized eventually.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "triggering the tiering up in the Liftoff assembler":

The function `LiftoffAssembler::CheckTierUp` should get called at least once whenever any Wasm function is compiled (as long as dynamic tiering is enabled, which is the default nowadays; if you're working with a very old version of V8, things will be different). In order for a function to get compiled, you either need to call it (just once is enough), or disable lazy compilation.

If you care about the actual tiering-up of the function, you need to spend a sufficient amount of time in the unoptimized version of the function, typically by calling it sufficiently many times. You can use the `--wasm-tiering-budget` flag to set a lower budget for testing.

(For the record: I'm intentionally not mentioning a specific call count that would trigger tiering-up, firstly because the mechanism is more nuanced than just looking at call counts, and secondly because that's an implementation detail that will change over time -- we have changed it before, and have plans to experiment with further changes in the future.)

Comment: Thank you so much.

I do care about the actual tiering-up of the function. I've been debugging with lldb and have a breakpoint on CheckTierUp but I've been unable to see it called once. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SpikerJG `LiftoffAssembler::CheckTierUp` emits code that will check for tier-up when that generated code is executed. For the actual tier-up, set your breakpoint in `Runtime_WasmTriggerTierUp`. And make sure that dynamic tiering is actually enabled. And if you need further help, post complete repro instructions of what you're doing (at least including: V8 version, GN args, Wasm module, operating system, hardware platform, command line flags used if any).

Comment: Thank you. I think one thing I'm struggling with is that I can't get my wasm code to run in d8 itself. I followed your instructions from here but it still wasn't working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747815/how-to-run-wasm-on-d8
Do you have any further advice? I keep getting an "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instance')" error

Comment: @SpikerJG That sounds like there's a bug in your JavaScript. If you need help, I can only repeat my earlier advice: post _complete_ repro instructions of what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you. Steps for repro: 
MacOS `12.1`
v8: `11.9.0.0`

Gn: 
`is_component_build = true
is_debug = true
target_cpu = "arm64"
v8_enable_backtrace = true
v8_optimized_debug = false
v8_target_cpu = "arm64"
`

Wasm module (converted via wat2wasm) 
`(module
  (func (export "add") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
    local.get 0
    local.get 1
    i32.add
  )
)`

JS Code:
`const buf = read(‘add.wasm', 'binary');
let res;
WebAssembly.instantiate(buf).then((x) => res = x, (error) => console.log("e"+error));
const { add } = res.instance.exports;
`

Comment: @SpikerJG: That code doesn't take into account that Promise completion callbacks are invoked "later", asynchronously. Specifically, `const { add } = res.instance.exports;` will be executed *before* the `(x) => res = x` handler runs, which explains why `res` is `undefined` when you're trying to read from it. Think of `Promise.then(foo)` as similar to `setTimeout(foo)`. Try moving any processing of the instantiation result into the Promise completion handler, or into further functions called from there. (That's not a V8 issue and not a Wasm issue; that's just how JavaScript Promises work.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Was able to get it to work.

Comment: As a quick follow-up, do you have any clarity on the `ool_label` component of the `CheckTierUp` function? How is that label computed? I see the TierupCheck function calls it and refers to an OutOfLineCode object but having a lot of trouble understanding it.

Comment: @SpikerJG I don't understand the question. The `ool_label` refers to the entry point of the out-of-line code. It's passed from the caller to `CheckTierUp`. It'll be bound to an actual location later, when the OOL code is emitted. See `Assembler::bind` for the backpatching logic.